# Should I share OkHttpClient between Retrofit and WebSocket?

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp

I'm trying to implement Websockets and Retrofit network requests in the same app.
I have a OkHttpClient:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build()
```

which is then used by retrofit:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .build()
```

Can I use the same client when opening WebSocket?

```
webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, listener)
```

And why?

Thanks!